# Reinstall locales?

Tags: dependencies, locale

I have been installing various tools on ubuntu 14.04 from the kali linux repo, via katoolin. After installing the tools that I needed I rebooted my computer and removed the kali linux repo from the ppa, also via katoolin. The problem after seems that the locales seemed to have uninstalled or stopped working. The language of the OS is still in English, however in settings under languages the locale is displayed as "c" and no others are available to choose from. The other concern this brings is that many programs wont install as locales is a dependency. I can't reinstall english locales as it also says that locales are an unmet dependency. The code output below:

```
    Reading package lists... Done
    Building dependency tree       
    Reading state information... Done
    You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
    The following packages have unmet dependencies:
    language-pack-en-base : Depends: locales (>= 2.3.6) but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: language-pack-en (>= 1:14.04+20150219) but it is not going to be installed
    postgresql-9.4 : Depends: locales but it is not going to be installed
    E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Locales itself will also not install. Output:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libc6 : Breaks: locales (< 2.19) but 2.13+git20120306-12.1 is to be installed
 libc6:i386 : Breaks: locales (< 2.19) but 2.13+git20120306-12.1 is to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

I would very much appreciate if anyone could help me solve this issue.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's the output if you try to install the locales package directly?

Comment: I added the output @GunnarHjalmarsson

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently the installed versions of libc6 and libc6:i386 are not from the Ubuntu repo. I'd try to fix it with the "force version" feature in Synaptic.

Comment: @RadekWojcik: Did it work? To be honest, I feared you'd need to reinstall as A.B. suggested.

Comment: yes it worked, just had to downgrade the 2 packages and locales installed just fine

Comment: @RadekWojcik May I know what u had done to solve the problem?